# Samsung washing machine on the fritz

Tags: appliances, washing-machine, samsung

[image: Flights Flashing]

I have a Samsung washing machine (WF42H5, if that means anything to you), about 5 years old, that suddenly stopped working. All of its lights flash on and off (see photo), and it is unresponsive to any buttons. Nothing strange happened to the washing machine or our electric service, it just stopped working for no apparent reason. I have unplugged it, and plugged it back in, and no change.

What little I have been able to find on the internet about this condition with Samsung washing machines is not encouraging. But I'm hoping that there might be some experts on this board who can point me to a possible fix.

Comment: flashing constantly or in morse code

Comment: We have a Samsung washer and dryer. The electronic display on the dryer is faulty but it apparently runs the correct cycle. I am not impressed with the reliability of Samsung washer/dryers.

Comment: Many  questions here and many broken not-very-old appliances on craigslist have warned me away from ever buying a Samsung appliance. Of any type.